# MySQL - Find a value from a row with a reference ID

Tags: mysql

I have the following table that records measurements (empty, 1/4, half, 3/4, full) and their date.

```
ID   m1    Time1        m2   time2       m3    Time3       m4   time4
1    half  01/02/2018   3/4  06/06/2018  full  07/06/2018
2    3/4   18/01/2018   full 30/06/2018  
3    full  26/04/2018    
4    1/4   01/02/2018   half 29/06/2018  3/4   01/08/2018  full 03/08/2018
```

Would it be possible to query the date when the measurement is half to get the following output:

```
ID  time_full
1   01/02/2018
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   29/06/2018
```

Or could we easily transform this longitudinal table into a cross sectional table like this

```
ID  m     time
1   half  01/02/2018
1   3/4   06/06/2018 
1   full  07/06/2018
2   3/4   18/01/2018   
2   full  30/06/2018
3   full  26/04/2018
(...)
```

Thank you

Comment: FWIW, in my estimation, the so-called 'longitudinal table' is a very poor design. The 'cross-sectional' table is better, but better still would be to store decimals..

Comment: it is a software that records the information that way, the measurements as text strings ad the dates as time stamps (I have included the date only to fit everything on the table), additionally the software might measure more than for times. Ideally I wanted a simple way to make it 'cross-sectional' table. I ended up using multiple 'case' statements and look only at the last 5 measurements for example to calculate average time from half to full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,
case m when 'half' then m else null end m,
case m when 'half' then time1 else null end time_full
from table
```

But your example, 4 is 1/4 and your showed it in your expected result.

Comment: Thank you I have ended up using a case statement for each measurement which worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
select 
    `ID`,
    coalesce(
        if (`m1` = 'half', `Time1`, null),
        if (`m2` = 'half', `time2`, null),
        if (`m3` = 'half', `Time3`, null),
        if (`m4` = 'half', `time4`, null)
    ) time_half
from _data
```